# IIF and color fill

Tags: reporting-services

I want to do a simple color fill in SSRS.
If the actor's name is anything but John Cena or Brad Pitt then highlight it in yellow. 
I am trying the following:

```
 =IIF(Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value <> "John Cena" OR (Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value <> "Brad Pitt"), "Black", "Yellow")
```

But this ends up filling everything yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue stems from using the not equals operator with a string value.  I think you may be better off using the `Contains` function with this one. Try the following expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value.Contains("John Cena") 
     OR (Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value.Contains("Brad Pitt"), "Black", "Yellow")
```

The other option that should work is using the `InStr` function like the following:

```
=IIF(Instr(Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value("John Cena") > 0
     OR Instr(Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value("Brad Pitt") > 0, "Black", "Yellow")
```

Alright, I'm not sure what version of Report Builder you're using, but I've got an additional possible solution.

```
=IIF(Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value LIKE "*John Cena*" 
     OR Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value LIKE "*Brad Pitt*", "Black", "Yellow")
```

If this third expression doesn't work, it may be better to add a column to your query and set this value in the SQL.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN PrimaryUserName LIKE "%John Cena%" 
           OR PrimaryUserName LIKE "%Brad Pitt%" 
         THEN "Black" 
         ELSE "Yellow" END As CellColor
```

Then, just set the cell color to `=Fields!CellColor.Value` and it should color things appropriately.

Comment: for some odd reason, my ssrs is not accepting Contains

Comment: @user185704 Edited my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Nope, now it gives me " The Backgroundcolor expression for the text box 'Actor' contains an error:[BC30455] argument not specified for parameter 'String32' of 'Public Function instr(start as integer, string1 as string, string2 as string, [compare as microsoft.visualbasic.comparemethod = microsoftbasic.comparemethod.binary]) as integer'

Comment: @user185704 Ok, I added two more possible solutions, including an option to do this at the query level.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your comparison, which will be true for every name - "John Cena" does not equal "Brad Pitt" so this part of the expression will be true and because you are using OR the overall expression will be true, and vice versa for "Brad Pitt". Every name does not equal both "John Cena" and "Brad Pitt", including "John Cena" and "Brad Pitt", so you always get yellow. You should be using `=` not `<>`.

What you want to do is check if the name is equal to either "John Cena" or "Brad Pitt" and colour those Black with everything else being Yellow:

```
=IIF((Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value = "John Cena") OR (Fields!PrimaryUserName.Value = "Brad Pitt"), "Black", "Yellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Output
[image]

GO to TextBox Propertiess of that cell

[image]

and I used below expression

```
=IIF((LCase(Fields!ActorName.Value)=LCase("John CEna")
OR LCase(Fields!ActorName.Value)=LCase("BraD PIT"))
,"Yellow","Green")
```